# Amplitude change when wave travels from one string to another

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A string consists of two parts attached at **x=0**.The right part of the string (x>0) has mass **'µr'** per unit length and the left part of the string (x<0) has mass **'µl'** per unit length, the tension in the string is T.If a wave of **unit** amplitude travels along the left part of the string, what is the amplitude of the wave that is transmitted to the right part of the string.

Comment: What is wrong with looking for an answer on the Internet? http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/waves/transverse.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a wave travel across medium a part of it gets reflected back and a part of it gets transmitted and the point $x=0$ will be a junction.Let $A_i$ be  amplitude of initial and $A_r$ be denoted as amplitude of  reflected wave and $A_t$ the amplitude of transmitted one.

$y_i = A_i sin(kx-\omega t)$

at x=0
$y_i + y_r = y_t \\
A_i + A_r=A_t$
Therefore
$\frac{dy_i}{dx}_{x=0^-} + \frac{dy_r}{dx}_{x=0^-}=\frac{dy_t}{dx}_{x=0^+}$
this gives $-A_i + A_r = A_t \frac{v_1}{v_2}$
Solving the two equations we obtain
$A_r=\frac{v_2-v_1}{v_1+v_2}A_i$ 
and 
$A_t=2\frac{v_{1}}{v_{1}+v_{2}}A_i$

Here $v_1=\sqrt{\frac{T}{ml}}$ and $v_2=\sqrt{\frac{T}{ mr }}$

Comment: There is a mistake in your second last step. Thank you for helping me , you cleared my doubt.

Comment: is it right now??

Comment: It should be 2v1 in the numerator

Comment: i was typing in mobile so ..sorry i guess